# Don't display login screen for user after signing in - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that the home screen is the login activity, I would like that after the user logs in this screen will no longer be displayed even if the user is using the back button on the phone. and always keep him logged in when you open the app. any solution not being sharedpreferences?

something that I can implement in mainactivity to solve this issue? in this case, the user would only return to activitylogin if he presses the exit button. the button event I do myself, I really need help with this method so that the user can no longer access the login page, not even by clicking back on the cell phone. any help is welcome.

my manifest is like this

```
<activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

LOGIN ACTIVITY CODE

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText emailTV, passwordTV;
    private Button loginBtn;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        initializeUI();

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginUserAccount();
            }
        });
        Button registrar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registrar);

        registrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegistroActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private void loginUserAccount() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        String email, password;
        email = emailTV.getText().toString();
        password = passwordTV.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "INSIRA E-MAIL...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "INSIRA SENHA!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOGADO COM SUCESSO!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FALHA AO LOGAR TENTE NOVAMENTE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void initializeUI() {
        emailTV = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        passwordTV = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }
}
```

MAINACTIVITY CODE

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    Button btn_send;
    TextView et_contact;
    TextView et_message;
    TextView Uemail;

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;




    private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        btn_send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
        et_contact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.et_contact);
        et_message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.et_message);
        Uemail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Uemail);


        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        //textView52.setText(firebaseUser.getEmail());
        firebaseDatabase = firebaseDatabase;

        Uemail.setText(firebaseUser.getEmail());





        PermissionToConnect();

        btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String number = et_contact.getText().toString();
                String message = et_message.getText().toString();

                try{
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sending Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });


        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String userUid = user.getUid();
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        ref.child("Users").child(userUid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String data = (String) dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue();
                et_message.setText(data);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });}






    private void PermissionToConnect(){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
            }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
      if(requestCode == 1) {
          if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
              if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Access", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          } else {
              Toast.makeText(this, "Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this. What I would suggest is don't make the login activity your main/launch activity. Instead, create an activity that will instantiate Firebase and check if the user has already logged in. If it has, launch whichever activity a logged in user should see, if it hasn't, launch the log in screen.